# How to don't show more tabs in Xamarin.Form Shell Flyout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am using the Xamarin.Form `Shell` Flyout.

I put all the pages in the `<flyoutitem>` so that the pages display the `Tabbar`, But I want to only have 4 elements in the `tabbar` (don't want to show More Tab). How do to do?

```
    <shell>
       <flyoutitem route="animals" flyoutdisplayoptions="AsMultipleItems">
          <shellcontent route="cats"/>
          <shellcontent route="dogs"/>
          <shellcontent route="monkeys"/>
          <shellcontent route="elephants"/>
          <shellcontent route="bears"/>
          <shellcontent route="about"/>
        </flyoutitem>
    </shell>
```

[image]

Comment: This will be an expected effect both in iOS and Android , which is caused by system design . You could set child tabbed page on a specific tabbed page (set multi ShellContent in the same tab).