# Enter the scroll property in the shellpage tabbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, scroll, tabbar

I have created a tabbed project, with the horizontal menu created by default, but having more tabs the "More" button is created automatically, I would like to delete it and insert the scroll property.`

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GET_SOUND.Views"
   Title="GET_SOUND"
   x:Class="GET_SOUND.AppShell">
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="Orange"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>




<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="DASHBOARD"  x:Name="Dashboard" Icon="dashboard" Route="Dashboard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dashboard}" />
    <ShellContent Title="MARCHI" x:Name="Marchi" Icon="marchi" Route="Marchi" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Marchi}" />
    <ShellContent Title="ISRC" x:Name="Isrc" Icon="matrici"  Route="Isrc" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Isrc}" />
    <ShellContent Title="DOCUMENTI" x:Name="Documenti" Icon="documenti" Route="Documenti" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Documenti}" />
    <ShellContent Title="IMPOSTAZIONI" x:Name="Impostazioni" Icon="imp" Route="Impostazioni" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Impostazioni}" />
    <ShellContent Title="ANAGRAFICA" x:Name="Anagrafica" Icon="anagrafica" Route="Anagrafica" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Anagrafica}" />
    <ShellContent Title="OPERE TUTELATE" x:Name="Opere" Icon="opere" Route="OpereTutelate" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OpereTutelate}" />
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Same like https://stackoverflow.com/q/61629680/ (no answer) ? an alternative is to use scrollable tabs from https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs

Comment: I tried to take a look but they don't seem to me the most suitable option

Comment: Hope this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455643/xamarin-tabbed-page-slide-tab-bar-instead-of-more-button) can help you.